# Data Binding Not Updating w/ Nested ngFor Loops

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, html-select, ngfor

I have a series of drop downs, one for each field to report on. Each drop down has a series of options (the same for each). The user has the ability to change the fields to report on or add more. The drop downs seem to initialize with the correct values, but don't update the model when the selection changes.

I can update the report model by hooking into *ngModelChange*, but that seems extra. I've had success in other areas, but not with a variable number of select boxes containing a variable number of string columns.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tv2bvc?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

***.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let field of report.summaryFields.defaultFields">
    <select [(ngModel)]="field">
        <option *ngFor="let column of columns" [(ngValue)]="column">{{column}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

***.ts**

```
report = {
    summaryFields: {
        defaultFields: ["FirstName", "LastName"],
        optionalFields: ["Age", "Grade"]
    }
};
columns = ["FirstName", "LastName", "Age", "Grade", "Teacher"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify an array element, you should bind using the array index, not the `ngFor` loop variable. Also, make sure that you bind the `option` value with `[ngValue]` or `[value]`, not with `[(ngValue)]`.

```
<div *ngFor="let field of report.summaryFields.defaultFields; let i = index">
  <select [(ngModel)]="report.summaryFields.defaultFields[i]">
    <option *ngFor="let column of columns" [ngValue]="column">{{column}}</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
    defaultFields: {{ report.summaryFields.defaultFields | json }}
</div>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xxx2jr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a demo. Please note that I use the `json` pipe to force the view to update the interpolation when a change is made.

Comment: You beat me to it by 10 min and I didn't even look :), deleting my redundant answer.